# DAX - How do I create a measure that filters a table based on a slicer value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables set up like this.

Table 1
[image: dim table]

Table 2
[image: date table]

I am trying to create a table visual using measures where I can aggregate the totals by date and account and based on the slicer have one column of the current amount and one column of the previous. For example, if a date slicer selected 12/31 the result would be 1 column with the sum by account of 12/31 and the next column would be the sum for 9/30

I have the selected slicer measure working, but I cannot get the previous amount measure to work. Here is the current amount measure formula:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(table1[amount]),
    FILTER(
        table1,
        table1[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE('table2'[Date])
    )
)
```

For the previous amount measure I tried:

```
VAR PrevDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Previous Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(table1[amount]),
    FILTER(
        table1,
        table1[date] = PrevDate
    )
)
```

The result is blank. I did create a measure that is just:

```
VAR PrevDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Previous Date])
RETURN PrevDate
```

This returns the correct date, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to use it in the calculation.

Comment: I would suggest you create a new column in table_1 with previous day's value in each row. This will make your calculations very easy.